# SQL query newest entry per customer

Tags: sql

I have an issue with a sql query.
There is a table with data for each day which holds information for nearly every day, per customer.

Here is a simplified example data for a span of 4 days, for 3 customers.

| Day | CustomerID | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20240101 | 1001 | 12 |
| 20240101 | 2002 | 4 |
| 20240101 | 3003 | 75 |
| 20240102 | 2002 | 5 |
| 20240102 | 3003 | 66 |
| 20240103 | 1001 | 13 |
| 20240103 | 1001 | 14 |
| 20240103 | 3003 | 67 |
| 20240104 | 1001 | 15 |
| 20240104 | 2002 | 1 |
| 20240104 | 2002 | 2 |

I need a result  like this. A Entry of the highest Day per Customer.

| Day | CustomerID | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20240103 | 3003 | 67 |
| 20240104 | 1001 | 15 |
| 20240104 | 2002 | 2 |

How do i achieve to get the counter of the last entry per day for each customer?
Grateful for your help.

Comment: can you please format your code better?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [ask]

Comment: Have a look at using window functions such as `row_number()`

Comment: What's the expected result if a customer has the same highest counter value twice, on separate days? Do you want both dates, or just one of them (which one)?

Comment: i don't need the highest counter. i will edit my op

Comment: Do you use sql-server as rdbms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Day, CustomerID, Counter,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Day DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Day, CustomerID, Counter
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Day, CustomerID;
```

Comment: Don't need to partition by Day, the OP wants the highest single day. Also, partition by should be CustomerID to match your cte column name.

Comment: this code is pretty close you just missed, that the last day is wanted not the highest counter by customer

Comment: @Yjn000 I missed that requirement, but I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tableone.Day, tableone.CustomerID, tableone.Counter
FROM your_table_name tableone
JOIN (
    SELECT Day, CustomerID, MAX(Counter) AS MaxCounter
    FROM your_table_name
    GROUP BY Day, CustomerID
) subquerytable ON tableone.Day = subquerytable.Day AND tableone.CustomerID = subquerytable.CustomerID AND tableone.Counter = subquerytable.MaxCounter;
```

Here tableone is your main table alias. Please  replace your_table_name with the actual name of your table.
in this query we create sub query (subquerytable) that groups the data by day and customer id. It will help to find the maximum encounter.

Comment: sry i dont need the max counter for the customer.